# MySQL Replace function throwing error

Tags: mysql, update, mysql-5.6, load

I am trying to update ^G (Ctrl G) in a table, below is scenario-

```
CREATE TABLET TEST(COLA INT,DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(20));
```

I have crtl G in my data for description field, so to replace it with a \,I am running following command-

```
UPDATE TEST 
SET DESCRIPTION=REPLACE(DESCRIPTION,CHAR(92),CHAR(7)) 
WHERE DESCRIPTION like '%' CHAR(07) '%';
```

It runs fine,converts the ^G into \ but it gives a warning as well

**TRUNCATED INCORRECT INTEGER VALUE '%'**

Can somebody please help me understand this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's odd, When I run your statements on 5.5 I get a syntax error:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE TEST(COLA INT,DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> UPDATE TEST 
    -> SET DESCRIPTION=REPLACE(DESCRIPTION,CHAR(92),CHAR(7)) 
    -> WHERE DESCRIPTION like '%' CHAR(07) '%';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
near 'CHAR(07) '%'' at line 3
```

Anyway, the proper way to do what you want to achieve would be concatenating `'%'` and the \G, that is:

```
UPDATE TEST 
SET DESCRIPTION=REPLACE(DESCRIPTION,CHAR(92),CHAR(7)) 
WHERE DESCRIPTION like CONCAT('%',CHAR(07),'%');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @redguy it worked for me and i also figured out why was the above one worked for me. Because MySQL was taking the first '%' and matching everything.